# Detection of smart card removal and insertion using PCSC in C

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I am using PCSC-lite v1.6.4 for my smartcard based application development.
I need a way to detect as soon as smart card is removed from reader and then to detect the insertion into reader so that smartcard will be forced to complete a specific process again.

If possible, is there any interrupt/event based way instead of simple polling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [SCardGetStatusChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925120.aspx) in WinSCard library.

> Blocks execution until the current availability of the cards in a specific set of readers changes.

Since PCSC Lite is a reimplementation of WinSCard library you can also use it in PCSC Lite ([here](https://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/api/group__API.html#ga33247d5d1257d59e55647c3bb717db24)). You can find several [examples](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?510947-How-to-detect-smart-card-reader-insertion&s=1fa537e13bd07881796f1e91e3a35374&p=2008033#post2008033).

Comment: Thanks for the link of the examples. It gave me a good start point. But there is little problem in dwEventState received after state change. Its third byte keeps on increasing by one whenever smartcard state changes. Is it ok? Can it overflow into actual status bytes?

Comment: In the examples link, the code is using 500ms for timeout. Will it be more appropriate to use INFINITE (-1) value for timeout here, since it will save a lot of CPU time?

Comment: Yes, you can use INFINITE as parameter. Then the function will never timeout. Are you sure `dwEventState` gets increased by one whenever smart card state changes? Maybe what you see is `SCARD_STATE_CHANGED` toggling ([SCARD_READERSTATE structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Yes, following are the values I get when I keep removing and inserting the card: 0X120, 0X10012, 0X20122, 0X30012, 0X40122, 0X50012 and so on. (These are printed using "%#X" format modifier in printf).

Comment: In PCSC Lite documentation (see link in my answer) i found: `dwEventState also contains a number of events in the upper 16 bits (dwEventState & 0xFFFF0000). This number of events is incremented for each card insertion or removal in the specified reader. This can be used to detect a card removal/insertion between two calls to SCardGetStatusChange()`. So from my perspective it should not be able to overflow into status bytes. Everything OK. By the way i suspect this event counter is not implemented in windows PCSC. Be careful when porting code to windows.

Comment: Great, this incrementing will be useful to detect if card was removed and inserted in between two SCardGetStatusChange() calls. That's all I needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now, detection works fine when any other thread is not using the card. But I have one thread2 which keeps transacting with card. So when I remove card while thread2 is running, thread2 gives this msg "SCardTransmit: Transaction failed." and my card_monitor thread is taking 2-3 sec to detect removal of smartcard. If I re-insert card without waiting for 2-3 sec after removal, card_monitor thread is not recognizing card insertion. Instead it gives message of card removal (actually this msg is getting printed when I remove and insert the card again.. weird!). Why could this be happening? Any idea?

Comment: Do you properly clean up allocated WinSCard ressources in your thread2 after you receive "SCardTransmit: Transaction failed."?

Comment: By WinSCard resources, do you mean hCard and hContext of that application? I am not cleaning that after this error. I want to close thread2 as soon as card is removed and thread1 should detect removal immediately. Also after insertion of card, I am connecting to card again before starting new instance of thread2. Sometimes, one more error "SCardConnect: Card unresponsive" occurs when connecting to card after insertion. I also have a doubt whether I need to reconnect the card after insertion or is there any other way to maintain connection?