# Event when smart card of the X509Certificate2 object is removed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, smartcard, x509certificate2

We have a feature where we use Windows' personal certificate store to authenticate using certificates after the user chooses a valid certificate. It simply signs a challenge with following:

```
public static byte[] SignDataSHA512RSA(X509Certificate2 certificate, byte[] data)
        {
            using (var rsa = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider)
            {
                if (rsa == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return rsa.SignData(data, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"));
            }
        }
```

It works pretty well using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class. The feature allows both regular certificates and smart card certificates. If there is a smart card and it requires PIN, windows prompts a dialog for it and all.

Now, there is an extra security requirement in this feature where if a smartcard is used for this operation (which we can find out by `rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.Removable`, and `HardwareDevice` if you want to enforce hardware), we want to make sure that it's accessible at all times during the session. In other words, we need an event when the smart card is removed so we can log out automatically.

One crude way would be having a timer job which checks `certificate.PrivateKey` is accessible every minute or so, but that doesn't throw before prompting user to insert the smart card and user presses `Cancel`.

The feature supports Windows 7 as well, so using the UWP libraries is not an option. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use PC/SC to check for card removal. In windows it is implemented in WinSCard library. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456748/detection-of-smart-card-removal-and-insertion-using-pcsc-in-c).

There is also a C# implementation [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp).

Comment: The library seems to work great. Thanks. However, there is still the challenge of correlating `X509Certificate2` to the smart card reader. If there are more than one smart card readers attached, I need to make sure that the right card removal triggers this. I've looked through the attributes in `X509Certificate2` and `SmartCardReader` attributes, but couldn't find anything matching. Only thing `X509Certificate2` has is `CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName (UUID/string)`, but not sure if that's even relevant really.

Comment: @Natan yes, that is a problem. In the old days of separate CSP it could be correlated to CSP name but even then you could not distinguish two cards from the same vendor. Now we have Base SmartCard Crypto Provider with its concept of minidrivers and it a pain working with it.

Comment: @Natan you could use [Pkcs11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net/) and do card search yourself when the card is inserted. In fact many vendor drivers do the same as some kind of caching so that they wouldn't have to read the whole card every time. But it means that you would have to know what pkcs#11 library to load and card reading is relatively slow. So ... you started with pure .net and ended up with 2 third party libraries :)

Comment: @Natan Or ... when the card is inserted do a diff of My (personal) store before and after the card insertion. card can be identified by its ATR and serial number.

Comment: hehe, was hoping to keep it simple :). The last idea won't work unless I'm misunderstanding the approach. Smart card may be already inserted at the time our application starts. Even assuming if that wasn't the case, "My" store keeps the certificate(s) even after you remove the smart cards, you just can't use the private keys; so in most cases inserting smart card won't change anything in the store.

Comment: @Natan Some vendors (i.e. Siemens CardOS) have the functionality to remove certificates from store after card removal. Maybe it can be configured for others as well.

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Just assumed they are all the same :). Thanks for that information.